# How to get currently installed OpenerDirector and handlers from Python urllib?

Tags: python, urllib, handler

## Problem

In Python's `urllib` you can create an `OpenerDirector` instance with a list of request handlers and install it as default opener. However, I would like to access the already installed default `OpenerDirector` to see and eventually alter its list of handlers.

**How can I do that?**

## Background

I have a complicated URL request where I need to access an FTP server with authentication via an HTTP proxy. It is a lab network, whose only connection to the internet is via the HTTP proxy.

This works with `wget` or `curl` calls, but instead of calling these by Python I would prefer to directly use a standard Python lib for that. In order to find out why it doesn't work yet, I'd like to have a close look at the involved handlers.